# Комментирование кода - ссылка в комментарии

Tags: c#

Какой тег нужно использовать в комментарии между `<summary></summary>` для того чтобы оставить URL и потом IntelliSense выдавал бы URL как активный - по которому можно перейти.

**UPD**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как `a` в HTML, только `see` (да и `a` вроде тоже подходит).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я что то пробовал и <see> и <seealso> ссылка не была активна - Спасибо - попробую ещё раз

Comment: Как вы пробовали? Вот как минимум 2 варианта: 1. `<a href="http://site">описание</a>` 2. `<see href="http://site">описание 2</see>`. В итоге получаем [это](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7Rz2.png). Так что наверно плохо пробовали, писали явно что то не так)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо! обновил пост с учетом вашей подсказки - как то так и пробовал. Ссылка в выпадающем окне IntelliSense неактивна - или это нормальное поведение ? И активна должна быть только внутри тегов ? UPD - Блин, а в вашем примере по img всё здорово

Comment: А если так? `<see cref="!:http://site">описание</see>`? Вообще тут я вам уже не помощник, ибо надо копаться в студии скорей всего, в ее версии, в ее настройках. У меня последняя, 2019, со всеми последними патчами, настройки вроде не трогал и как видите все отображает как надо.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Так тоже не работает( У меня 2017 - настройки дефолтные - сам ничего не трогал. Спасибо! Буду копаться или на 2019 переходить.

Comment: По сути вы можете найти/написать расширение для студии, я например нашел [это](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EWoodruff.ExtendedDocCommentsProvider), правда пишет, что опять же для 2019 (но попробовать стоит), может еще какие есть (долго не искал). Но так да, если есть возможность, то лучше используйте всегда свежий софт для разработки.